How to fetch user posts from Linkedin
I am making an app where a user can sign in via LinkedIn (oAuth) and after that he can see his recent posts (activity feed). I am struggling to find that API end point with which I can retrieve the user's posts. Is there any such end point available

Did you read their API documentation?

this API gives access to user's posts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/integrations/shares/ugc-post-api
UGC belongs to Compliance API category and LinkedIn is not giving access to it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#compliance-closed

I think these two might be of most help for you:
Find Posts by Account
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?dscAdAccount={encode dscAdAccount}&q=dscAdAccount&dscAdTypes=List(STANDARD,VIDEO)

Find Posts by Authors
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author={encoded person urn or organization urn like urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A5abc_dEfgH or urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A2414183}&q=author&count=10&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED

Read this to learn about URNs:

URNs are used to represent foreign associations to an entity (persons,
organizations, and so on) in an API. A URN is a string-based
identifier with the format:
urn:{namespace}:{entityType}:{id}
For example:
urn:li:person:123
urn:li:organization:456
urn:li:sponsoredAccount:789

URNs encode more information, including the entity type. Using the
entity type, it's possible to dereference a URN and access the
underlying data of the entity using a process called decoration.
URN values returned from LinkedIn's APIs are a maximum of 255
characters in length. IDs
Simple integer IDs are returned to represent an object's primary key.
Your application should support transforming URNs into IDs and vice
versa. IDs versus URNs
IDs are self-referencing identifiers similar to a primary key. URNs
are Globally Unique Identifiers (GUID) used to represent an entity's
foreign associations.
In the example below, we fetch details about a share and use a
projection to limit the results to the id and owner fields. The shares
API returns an id that is the primary key and an owner that is a
foreign reference to the person who created the share in the form of a
URN.


Spot on! Thank you so much @TheNomad <3

this API gives access to user's posts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/integrations/shares/ugc-post-api
UGC belongs to Compliance API category and LinkedIn is not giving access to it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#compliance-closed
Seems like we can't do it
